# Texto que se encuentra antes y después de una palabra CHARINDEX

Tags: sql-server

Tengo una cadena, la cual no siempre tiene la misma longitud, pero lo que estoy tratando de hacer es traer solamente el texto que se encuentra después de 'Accion="' y antes de '" Desde'

Esta es la cadena completa (De_parametros):

```xml
<VacioLimitacion **Accion="Limitar" Desde**="PA54973" Hasta="PA54523" IdViaje="14" ViajeLinea="1" />
```

Estoy usando esto por el momento, pero no me trae el resultado esperado (Limitar):

```
SUBSTRING( SUBSTRING(DE_PARAMETROS, 0, CHARINDEX('Accion="', DE_PARAMETROS)), NULLIF(CHARINDEX( '" Desde', DE_PARAMETROS), 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Para lograr esto, tienes dos opciones: Usar funciones de texto como lo que estás haciendo, o usar funciones de XML.

Para usar funciones de texto, necesitas encontrar el inicio de la cadena que necesitas. En este caso, buscas la cadena `Accion=` y le agregas 8 caracteres que cuentan la palabra, el signo de igual y las primeras comillas. Ese cálculo lo presento usando la operación `APPLY` para evitar repetirla. Teniendo ese valor, podemos usarlo para encontrar las siguientes comillas que mostrarían el final de ese valor. Eso lo hacemos gracias al tercer parámetro de `CHARINDEX`.

Las funciones de XML son más directas y solo necesitas convertir la cadena en xml. Después solo usas el método value con la ruta deseada y, en este caso, un arroba para indicar que se trata de un atributo y no del valor. El `[1]` es para indicar que solo queremos regresar la primera instancia de este y así cumplir con regresar un valor escalar. Por último, tenemos que asignar un tipo de dato al valor que va a regresar.

Ejemplo:

```
DECLARE @Tabla table(
    DE_PARAMETROS varchar(1000)) 
INSERT INTO @Tabla 
VALUES( '<VacioLimitacion Accion="Limitar" Desde="PA54973" Hasta="PA54523" IdViaje="14" ViajeLinea="1" />');

SELECT *, 
    SUBSTRING( t.DE_PARAMETROS, inicio, CHARINDEX( '"', t.DE_PARAMETROS, inicio) - inicio),
    CAST( DE_PARAMETROS AS xml).value( '(/VacioLimitacion/@Accion)[1]', 'varchar(100)')
FROM @Tabla t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT NULLIF( CHARINDEX( 'Accion=', t.texto), 0) + 8 AS inicio) x
```

Comment: Cómo se podría hacer para obtener sólo el valor que viene después, es decir en este caso sería "Limitar"

Comment: El ejemplo muestra ambas opciones para obtenerlo.

Comment: Hice algo similar viendo tu ejemplo y me quedo lo siguiente:   SUBSTRING(DE_PARAMETROS,CHARINDEX('Accion="',de_parametros,8)+8,CHARINDEX('" D',DE_PARAMETROS,1)-2)
Pero no me queda el valor que se encuentra entre esas palabras u_u Lo estoy haciendo de esta manera, ya que luego debo pasarlo a una columna derivada para un etl